# Why it is not reading edit details funtion

Tags: visualforce

Problem being shown here is - Unknown property 'Class__cStandardController.editDetails'

VF page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Class__c" extensions="ManageClassController">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!classList}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
            <apex:commandButton title="Edit" action = "{!edit}" value="Edit">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!classId}" value="{!c.id}" />
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton title="Delete" action = "{!delete}" value="Delete">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!classId}" value="{!c.id}" />
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!editDetails}">

        <apex:form >
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyClass.name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyClass.fee__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyClass.detailed_description__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyClass.max_size__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dummyClass.my_count__c}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action = "{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:form>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Apes class -

```
public class ManageClassController {
public List classList{get;set;} 
public String classId{get;set;} 
public class__c dummyClass{get;set;} 
public ManageClassController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){ this.classList = new List([SELECT id , name from class__c]); } 

public void edit(){ 
editDetails(); 
} 

public boolean editDetails(){ 
if(this.classId != null){ 
this.dummyClass = [SELECT id , name , fee__c , detailed_description__c , max_size__c , my_count__c FROM class__c where id = :classId]; this.classId = null; return true; 
}
return false; 
} 
}
```

This section is under development but still it would fetch edit details why is it not doing so

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code so the community can read it.

Answer (score 1):

`editDetails()` is a function, not a property; one does not invoke functions in Visualforce that way. Rather, functions are invoked via such things as `<apex:commandButton>` and other locations where action functions may be fired.

Instead, you should implement getter functions if you need logic around the values that will be used *during rendering*. For example, something like this:

```
public Boolean editDetails {
    get {
        return dummyClass != null;
    }
    private set;
}
```

I suspect there's some more restructuring that needs to be done here once your page becomes more functional or complete, but this does cover your immediate syntax issue. I'm not sure you want to be using a standard controller at all if you're proposing to view and edit from a list of records.